# Spec for http health checks?

Tags: monitoring, specifications, nagios, health-monitoring

I want to implement a simple health check and make it available via http.

Up to now I have only experience writing nagios plugins. Nagios has this [API spec](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/pluginapi.html)

Is there already a common way how to write vendor-neutral health checks?

If not, what should a sane health check return to make it portable to many different monitoring server implementations?

Comment: How could HTTP as a protocol be not vendor neutral? Whose health do you want to check from what aspects? The purpose of an HTTP health check is usually only to verify that that the web server whose health is being checked is functioning normally. An empty response should suffice. So long as the server is able to respond, the test is passed.

Comment: @marekful HTTP is the transport layer. I could use IP over Avian Carriers, too. I am interested in the syntax and sematic of the health check output. This question is about data formats, not about how to transport the data. HTTP does already provide a nice feature: The status code. But I think this is not enough.

Comment: You don't specify details and the the only link in the question is irrelevant to the problem. What components are in your system? Which of those components' health do you want to check?

Comment: @marekful could you please elaborate why the provided link to the nagios API is irrelevant? For me this is what it is all about: The spec of the data structure which gets returned by the health-check.

Comment: short answer: no, there is no common standard. But I'm still confused about what you are looking for. Nagios API cited by you provides for a (nearly minimal) status abstraction (4 "states"). As a minimal model this will be usable by a variety of monitoring servers.

Comment: For the general approach you would need to specify a naming scheme for addressing items/components to be monitored or available for monitoring. Then, of course, you need to provide a health state abstraction. (True minimum would be e.g.: OK, BAD). Another aspect to cope with is whether the monitoring is triggered externally by a client (monitoring server) or provided by the entity monitored (e.g. notifications).

Comment: And may be you turn to keep this dynamically extendable, as in some circumstances true health information might require target specific, fine grain detail data. (E.g. when monitoring temperature).

Comment: Some of these aspects might be addressed by standards like _SNMP_. So, look at those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no standard for format of health checks, you should consider major monitoring tools and their expectations from your protocol.
In most cases they react to specific HTTP answer codes.
For example [Amazon Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-creating.html):

> waits for an HTTP status code of 200 or greater and less than 400

Another tool, Consul, has [more specific definition](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/checks.html):

> The status of the service depends on the HTTP response code: any 2xx code is considered passing, a 429 Too Many Requests is a warning, and anything else is a failure.

So you might need to check a few top tools you might integrate later and choose an approach suitable for all of them.

Comment: I am amazed that there is not standard up to now. But maybe "http status 200 is OK, everything else is not ok" is enough.